# Does Taifun's sortable listview trim spaces

Tags: list, listview, jquery-ui-sortable, app-inventor

I am using the [sortable list view](https://puravidaapps.com/sortable.php) by @Taifun in one of my apps, and I am trying to debug a problem with the values that I get from the list.

The user adds items to the list and then they are saved to a custom tinyWebDB.

My question is this- Does the sortable list remove leading or trailing spaces either when loading the list or when getting the value back out? If so, is there any way to disable or fix this behavior?

I can't figure out why the values my app is storing are wrong, and I can't see whether the items have trailing spaces just from looking at the list view.

If it isn't the list view, it might be the way I am sorting the items.

Comment: you might want ot find this out yourself while debugging your app, see also tip 4 here https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php

Comment: Good point, I will check. Thank you.

Comment: @Taifun I wrote a procedure to replace the leading and trailing spaces with ^ and convert them back when saving. It works now, thanks for the help.

Comment: great! you might want to provide your procedure as answer... this might help others with the same question in future...

Comment: @Taifun I added an answer with the aia and screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment above, I wrote a procedure to replace the leading and trailing spaces with ^ in the list view and convert them back when saving.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r71VT4RHboTIQPLBmcgICl-uEeLO3ajL/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the aia file.

The aia is set up for what I was using it for- displaying two lists side by side. I did this by adding a [dash "‒"](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp) between the items of each list. If you are not using the list in this way, you only need to copy the two procedures that are shown below.

[image: fix trail procedure]

This procedure replaces leading and trailing spaces with the ^ mark by checking if the first or last characters are spaces. If the string is longer than 2 characters, those are put in the middle without changing.

[image: add spaces procedure]

This procedure does the opposite and converts the ^'s that are in the first and last characters back into spaces.